# How to install cx_freeze 5.0.2 for python 3.5.2?

Tags: apt, software-installation, python

I am running ubuntu 16. I have both python 2.7 and 3.5 installed. I want to install cx_freeze latest version for python3. I downloaded the package from their website but couldn't run the setup.py file as it always gave me errors. Also i have installed pip3, but it still doesn't work for me. all the answers online are for older version of cx_freeze so a fresh answer for the new version will be helpful.

Comment: [so] is probably better place to ask this question (provided that more details are given).

Comment: What are the error messages you see? Please provide details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cx-Freeze can be installed using pip from the python-pip package in the default Ubuntu repositories. pip has been updated to the latest version (pip-9.0.1) using the command `sudo -H pip2 install --upgrade pip`

```
sudo pip install cx_Freeze
Collecting cx_Freeze
Installing collected packages: cx-Freeze
Successfully installed cx-Freeze-5.0.2

>>> import cx_Freeze
>>> dir(cx_Freeze)
['ConfigError', 'ConstantsModule', 'Executable', 'Freezer', 'Module', 'ModuleFinder', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__version__', 'bdist_rpm', 'build', 'build_exe', 'common', 'hooks', 'install', 'install_exe', 'main', 'setup', 'sys', 'version']
```

To install cx_Freeze for Python 3.x use pip3 from the python3-pip package in the default Ubuntu repositories and update pip3 to the latest version using the command: `sudo -H pip3 install --upgrade pip`

Comment: I am getting a errors while doing so,  can you tell me how to post the errors ?

Comment: Copy all the errors to [Ubuntu Pastebin](http://paste.ubuntu.com/) and provide a link to it in a comment. Also you need to preface `pip` with `sudo` if you are installing a Python package outside of a Python virtual environment (i.e. globally) or else `pip` will try to install the package anyway but you'll get errors.